# Section entries - order by random

Tags: templating, entries, ordering

I was wondering if it's was possible to order section entries by random.

Example:

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('team').type('mainPeople').order('title random)) %}
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can use MySQL's [RAND()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand) function inside your order method:

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('team').type('mainPeople').order('RAND()') %}
```

Comment: Doh! I'd tried that, but forgot the quote marks. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`.order()` is deprecated in Craft 3 and doesn't work in Craft 4, use `orderBy()` instead.

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('team').type('mainPeople').orderBy('RAND()') %}
```