# Random posts displayed but exclude current entry ID

Tags: entry, random

I am brand new to Craft and can't find much support on this problem online. I have my entry pages and at the bottom of them, I have a div with the code below in it which randomly links to any entry.

I now would like this to disallow the entry that I am on from that randomization. I assume from other threads it would be something to do with finding the ID of the entry the user is on and not allowing it in the randomize?

```
{% for image in randomEntry.projectFeaturedImage %}

    <a href="{{ randomEntry.url }}">{{ randomEntry.title }}</a>
    <a href="{{ randomEntry.url }}">See Project</a>

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a couple of useful stackexchange questions

- Getting a random entry: [Section entries - order by random](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/2675/section-entries-order-by-random)
- Excluding the current entry: [Exclude Current Entry](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1275/exclude-current-entry/)

Putting that together:

```
{% set randomEntry = craft.entries({
  id: 'not '~entry.id,
  order: 'RAND()'
}).first %}
```

This will fetch entries whose id is not `entry.id` (`entry` is the current entry), ordered randomly, and then give you the first of those.

Probably you want to specify the section or sections to fetch your entries from:

```
{% set randomEntry = craft.entries({
  section: ['thisSection', 'thatSection', 'theOtherSection'],
  id: 'not '~entry.id,
  order: 'RAND()'
}).first %}
```

This will do the same thing, but only fetch entries from those 3 sections.

After all of that, you should also be sure to test that there actually is an entry:

```
{% if randomEntry %}
  ... do your thing ...
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Awesome thank! I got most the way there using other threads but couldn't figure out how to add the " id: 'not '~entry.id " to what I had:
 {% set randomEntry = craft.entries.section('projects').order('RAND()').first() %}